# Solaris - internal Compiler Error : cg_inbuf_emit() missed/messed up relocation

Tags: c, compiler-errors, linker-errors, solaris

We have a C codebase which used to build successfully with SunStudio 12.1 and Solaris 11.3 but recently we have upgraded our OS to Solaris 11.4 and build starts to break with either of below errors.

"<FILE_NAME>", line <LINE_NUMBER>: internal compiler error: cg_inbuf_emit(): messed up relocation
cc: acomp failed for <FILE_NAME>
*** Error code 2

Or

"<FILE_NAME>", line <LINE_NUMBER>: internal compiler error: cg_inbuf_emit(): missed relocation
cc: acomp failed for <FILE_NAME>
*** Error code 2

On inspection I observed that these lines are nothing but ending of either Macro definitons or symbols both which are referenced from other user defined libraries.

Comment: An ICE means that the compiler recognizes it has screwed up — it probably isn't a fault in your code per se.  Create a minimal reproduction and report to Oracle.

Comment: Have you updated your ***compiler***? 12.1 was originally released in 2009 and it [doesn't appear to be supported on Solaris 11](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/820-7601/gempq/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those indicate problems in the compiler that you will need to open a support request with Oracle to have them resolve.

Comment: I suspect the compiler is out-of-date and needs to be updated.